# Print the next line after match

Tags: perl

My input:

```
# BLASTN 2.13.0+
# Query: ;HaelonEVm219174t4;
# Database: /data1/IxoSca/Databases/nt/nt
# Fields: subject id, subject sci names, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, evalue, bit score, % query coverage per hsp, subject title
# 1 hits found
gi|1962480099|emb|LR990882.1|   Endotricha flammealis   80.702  57  11  0   0.043    54.5   10  Endotricha flammealis genome assembly, chromosome: 29
# BLASTN 2.13.0+
# Query: ;HaelonEVm2775195t2;
# Database: /data1/IxoSca/Databases/nt/nt
# Fields: subject id, subject sci names, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, evalue, bit score, % query coverage per hsp, subject title
# 1 hits found
gi|2452922202|emb|OX438846.1|   Eudonia truncicolella   88.372  43  3   1   0.009   53.6    29  Eudonia truncicolella genome assembly, chromosome: 21
```

My code:

```
}
elsif($line =~ m/\s[1] hit/){
    print "1 hits found: ".$name."\n";
            $flag=1;
}
```

My output:

```
HaelonEVm219174t4   1 hits found: # Query: ;HaelonEVm219174t4;
HaelonEVm2775195t2  1 hits found: # Query: ;HaelonEVm2775195t2;
```

I want to print the next line in place of
****"1 hits found: # Query: ;HaelonEVm219174t4;"****

Expected output:

```
HaelonEVm219174t4   LR990882.1   Endotricha flammealis   80.702  57  11  0   0.043    54.5   10  Endotricha flammealis genome assembly, chromosome: 29
HaelonEVm2775195t2  OX438846.1   Eudonia truncicolella   88.372  43  3   1   0.009   53.6    29  Eudonia truncicolella genome assembly, chromosome: 21
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the regex matches, set the flag but don't print anything for that line.  When the flag is set, print the current line, then clear the flag.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $flag = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (m/\s[1] hit/) {
        $flag = 1;
    }
    elsif ($flag) {
        print;
        $flag = 0;
    }
}

__DATA__
# BLASTN 2.13.0+
# Query: ;HaelonEVm219174t4;
# Database: /data1/IxoSca/Databases/nt/nt
# Fields: subject id, subject sci names, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, evalue, bit score, % query coverage per hsp, subject title
# 1 hits found
gi|1962480099|emb|LR990882.1|   Endotricha flammealis   80.702  57  11  0   0.043    54.5   10  Endotricha flammealis genome assembly, chromosome: 29
# BLASTN 2.13.0+
# Query: ;HaelonEVm2775195t2;
# Database: /data1/IxoSca/Databases/nt/nt
# Fields: subject id, subject sci names, % identity, alignment length, mismatches, gap opens, evalue, bit score, % query coverage per hsp, subject title
# 1 hits found
gi|2452922202|emb|OX438846.1|   Eudonia truncicolella   88.372  43  3   1   0.009   53.6    29  Eudonia truncicolella genome assembly, chromosome: 21
```

Prints:

```
gi|1962480099|emb|LR990882.1|   Endotricha flammealis   80.702  57  11  0   0.043    54.5   10  Endotricha flammealis genome assembly, chromosome: 29
gi|2452922202|emb|OX438846.1|   Eudonia truncicolella   88.372  43  3   1   0.009   53.6    29  Eudonia truncicolella genome assembly, chromosome: 21
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with setting a flag. But instead of printing immediately, print when the flag is true.

```perl
my $flag = 0;
while (<>) {
   if ( $flag ) {
      print $line;
       $flag = 0;
   }

   if ( $line =~ m/\s1 hit/ ) {
      $flag = 1;
   }
}
```

---

Simplified version:

```perl
my $flag = 0;
while (<>) {
   print if $flag;
   $flag = /\s1 hit/;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're on a system which supports the -A argument to grep, try:

$a = qx/grep -A 1 hits data.txt | grep -v found/;

Hyphen "-A 1" means the matching line and one line after
grep -v found removes the matching line